# Double segue from auth view

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, storyboard, segue

I'm having a conceptual design dilemma here with a view that I'd like to re-use.

**This is what I have:**

[image]

**My question is:** Am I getting into bad practices here for accessing this view without the proper authentication? I really need to be able to set that value from the auth screen and then at any point the user wants to, so:

1) Should I do what I'm doing?
2) Should I duplicate the view to avoid the double link from the auth controller?

No sensitive information is held in the settings view.

Thanks in advanced,